# Converting ConfigurationParameter to string in TeamCity

Tags: powershell, teamcity

I`m using Git and Powershell configuring build steps in TeamCity.
I need to extract Git Tag for the custom commit when doing custom build in TeamCity.

So I introduced ConfigurationParameter %CustomRevision% (of type Text) in TeamCity and before starting the custom build I manually fill in this parameter providing hash of the commit.

Than using PowerShell script, I compose a string to run the git command:

```
$customRevision = "%CustomRevision%"
$cmdGetExactTag = -join "git describe --exact-match --abbrev=0 --tags", $customRevision, "--always"

$tag = Invoke-Expression $cmdGetExactTag
```

But powershell can not convert "%CustomRevision%" to string giving me the Exception:

```
Invoke-Expression : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Command'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell7046746237377169989.ps1:18 char:25
+ $tag = Invoke-Expression <<<<  $cmdGetExactTag 
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], Parame 
terBindingException
[12:48:14][Step 3/4]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comma 
[12:48:14][Step 3/4]    nds.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

How I should properly convert "%CustomRevision%" to a String for PowerShell?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: Move the `-join` operator to the right of the input arguments: `"git describe --exact-match --abbrev=0 --tags", $customRevision, "--always" -join " "`

Comment: if I do that then I have: Invoke-Expression : Missing expression after unary operator '--'.
At C:\BuildAgent\temp\buildTmp\powershell5077669800046396338.ps1:18 char:25
+ $tag = Invoke-Expression <<<<  $cmdGetExactTag 
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (--:String) [Invoke-Expression], Pa 
rseException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator,Microsoft.PowerSh 
ell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing the command directly to allow powershell to expand the variable inline (without 'join')?

As in:

```
$cmdGetExactTag = "git describe --exact-match --abbrev=0 --tags $customRevision --always"
```

I think the resolution of the teamcity parameter may be happening but the problem is around the syntax for the join.  The solution presented is to point out that the join for this particular case does not seem necessary.

Comment: You could even refactor this to $cmdGetExactTag = "git describe --exact-match --abbrev=0 --tags %CustomRevision% --always"

Comment: I found the reason why I had a problem, I had to do                  `$customRevision = "%CustomRevision%" $customRevision.Trim().TrimEnd()`                                                          that is unbelievable ! Thank you for the help guys!